# Changing OnTouchListener of DragSortListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm using the [DragSortListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) library, and it's really nice.   I'd like to implement swipe gestures to let the user swipe back to the previous screen.  However, this class has already implemented an OnTouchListener to deal with drag and drop.

This question need not be specific to this one library but how can I override the OnTouchListener already registered with my ListView and change the way it handles swipe gestures?  There is no "getOnTouchListener" or similar function that I'm aware of.

Comment: Hi, I need to do the same thing - did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No, sorry.  It's not good design have swipe do anything else when using this library anyway.